# Filebeat Process multilne XML

Tags: xml, logging, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have a log file where I am printing request and response XML bodies. This log file also has some additional lines that are not XML. Example below --

```
===========================================
<request>
  <data>
    abc
 </data>
</request>
some random lines concerning the processing of request..
fha;js;fkgak;gj;kj;a
jgahkg;gaj;
Now response follows 
<response>
 <output>
  def
</output>
</response>
===================================================
```

How to use use filebeat [multiline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html) feature to parse such a data and have each XML as a single event to be sent to logstash?

Answer (score 0):

`multiline.pattern: ^<request>
 multiline.negate : true
 multiline.match  : after`

you need to insert above mentioned line in filebeat.yml file
this will capture all your data lying between as a single event beginning with **`<request>`** before the next **`<request>`** is found.you can modify your multipline.pattern(regex expression) as per your requirement.

for a detailed information check out following link:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/1.2/configuration-filebeat-options.html

Comment: As mentioned,the log file also includes some random text in between two xml objects. I would like the filebeat to ignore such kind of text

Comment: you can try using: **multiline.pattern: ^<re** **multiline.negate : true** **multiline.match  : after** with **include_lines: ['<request>(\n|.)*</request>','<response>(\n|.)*</response>']** or you can try some other similar combination.

Comment: As you see, this pattern is matching some random lines between two different xml object, false <request>
true   <data>
true     abc
true  </data>
true </request>
true some random lines concerning the processing of request..
true fha;js;fkgak;gj;kj;a
true jgahkg;gaj;
true Now response follows 
false <response>
true  <output>
true   def
true </output>
true </response>

Comment: as mentioned in their documentation if multline.pattern is used then it converts the expression into a single line,later if we apply a include/exclude line filter then it is either ignoring the whole line or it is not ignoring at all. as a result unable to come up with the desired result.

Comment: after multiline your outpur is like `<request>abc</request>agsdhfjklloiuhb` so either it is removing the whole line or it is not.i guess there are not much other filters provided as they have kept filebeat as ligjtweight as possible.